# RecursiveIteratorIterator to fetch subdirectories

Tags: php

Currently I am working with directories through php. I am able to list subdirectories for any given directory. However, the results are not 100% what I am looking for. The below code returns subdirectories but in addition it also returns the main directory in the array. How can I only return subdirectories of directory?

```
$root = '/test';

$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied"
);

$paths = array($root);
foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
    if ( $dir->isDir() ) {
        $paths[] = $path;
    }
}
```

Current output

```
Array ( [0] => /test [1] => /test/asf8 [2] => /test/some2 [3] => /test/something )
```

Desired output

```
Array ( [0] => /test/asf8 [1] => /test/some2 [2] => /test/something )
```

Comment: If you don't want to return the `/test` directory, then don't add it to the array. Just remove the `$paths = array($root);` line, or change it to `$paths= array();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change

```
if ( $dir->isDir() )
```

to

```
if ( $dir->isDir() && $dir != $root)
```

to remove the root directory